# Is there any way to avoid "insert at first empty index"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python3 and I want to insert Int at a specific index using insert() function.
I know that the function will first attempt to insert it at the first empty index before my specified index. Is there any way to avoid this behavior and insert in my specified index first?
trying to do the following:

```
[18, 6, 6, 6, 1, -1]
```

But the actual result is as follows:

```
[18, -1, 6, 1, 6, 6]
```

```
def replaceElements(self, arr: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        res = []
        temp = -1
        for index in range(len(arr)-1, -1, -1):
            res.insert(index, temp)
            if arr[index] > temp:
                temp = arr[index]
        return res
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using to get the actual result.

Comment: " I know that the function will first attempt to insert it at the first empty index before my specified index." Huh? What **exactly** are you doing?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html. index is always required for insert

Comment: Considering python is 0 indexed , you could just insert at value +1 ?

Comment: As it is currently posed, this question does not make any sense. It refers to an `insert` function, but the only one that exists in standard Python is `list.insert` which doesn't behave at all the way the questioner implies (for example, because there is no such thing as an "empty" index in a normal list). If you're referring to some other function, you need to show it to us or we can't answer any questions about it!

Comment: I just added the code and what I am trying to do.

Comment: What is this code *supposed to do?* In any case, you are modifying your list, so your indices are going to become misaligned, probably. It's easier to simply not modify a list in-place and to create a new one, otherwise, you will have to take into account how your list has changed. Also, you **still haven't told us exactly what you are doing**. What are you passing to your function?

Comment: I want to append into res[] but backward starting from the last index which is 5 in my case.